# Should I commit an empty .env file?

Tags: git, dotenv

I have a **.env** file storing my database information, and I'm about to publish my project on GitHub. So, my question is, should I commit an empty **.env** file with the keys that I need, but without the values so other people can understand how to fulfill it (and may later add it to the **.gitignore** file)?

For example, if my **.env** file looks like this:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=s1mpl3
```

Should I commit it like this or just don't commit it at all?

```
DB_HOST=
DB_USER=
DB_PASS=
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should commit, but with another name, like `.env.example`.
With that empty env, another team member can know how the env looks like and can fill in by themself.

Comment: Nice! By the way, this explains the wp-config-sample.php file in WordPress.

Answer (score 3):

No. If you add a `.env` to Git, any future changes to `.env` will be seen by Git. They may be accidentally committed.

Adding a file Git is already tracking to `.gitignore` has no effect.

> A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore.
> Files already tracked by Git are not affected

For example, I've added and committed an empty `.env` and then modified it.

```
$ cat .gitignore 
.env

$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   .env

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git diff
diff --git a/.env b/.env
index 4a263e9..94d2d70 100644
--- a/.env
+++ b/.env
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-DB_HOST=
-DB_USER=
-DB_PASS=
+DB_HOST=host
+DB_USER=user
+DB_PASS=pass
```

Add `.env` to your `.gitignore` and do not track it. Document your environment variables in your install and configuration documentation.